# Missing attributes running pyserial under Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyserial

I'm trying to run MinimalModbus (which uses pyserial under the hood) on Windows 7, and I've reduced my issue to this:  Here's the contents of `foo.py` in its entirety:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import serial
print(sys.version)
print(serial.PARITY_NONE)
```

When I run foo.py, python cannot find some pyserial attributes:

```
E:\>py -3.6 foo.py
3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(serial.PARITY_NONE)
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'PARITY_NONE'
```

When I run the same script on OS X (High Sierra, 10.13.2), I get the correct output ('N').

Here is the output of `pip freeze` and `ver` in my Windows environment:

```
E:\>py -3.6 -m pip freeze
future==0.16.0
iso8601==0.1.12
MinimalModbus==0.7
pyftdi==0.28.2
pyserial==3.4
pyusb==1.0.2
PyYAML==3.12
serial==0.0.27
UniCurses==1.2

E:\>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Any suggestions?

### update

It appears that I'm getting the wrong serial module:

```
    E:\>py -3.6
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> help(serial)
Help on package serial:

NAME
    serial

DESCRIPTION
    ``serial`` is an object serialization/deserialization library intended to fa
cilitate authoring of API models which are
    readable and introspective, and to expedite code and data validation and tes
ting. ``serial`` supports JSON, YAML, and
    XML.
```

... which isn't at all the pyserial module I've come to love.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is `foo.py`s real name `serial.py`..?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no, but see update.  I think I merely have to uninstall the offending serial module.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat anticlimactic solution.

I noticed the offending `serial` module in the output of `pip freeze`:

```
E:\>py -3.6 -m pip freeze
future==0.16.0
iso8601==0.1.12
MinimalModbus==0.7
pyftdi==0.28.2
pyserial==3.4
pyusb==1.0.2
PyYAML==3.12
serial==0.0.27    <<< this one
UniCurses==1.2
```

I removed it:

```
py -3.6 -m pip uninstall serial
```

... but that didn't fix the problem.  However, subsequently uninstalling and re-installing `pyserial` did the trick:

```
>>> py -3.6 -m pip uninstall pyserial
>>> py -3.6 -m pip install pyserial
>>> py -3.6 foo.py
3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
N
```

All better now!

Comment: The question now is;  What has been broken that originally used that "other" serial module?   I ran into this same problem and am going to use your solution, but I don't know what I installed that used that serialization module.   I haven't time to track it down but it's sure to bite me in the future.   Thanks for posting your "fix" anyway!